# error in working with speech_recognition in section of pyaudio

Tags: python, python-3.x, speech-recognition, pyaudio, pyaudioanalysis

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Anu Nema\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\speech_recognition\__init__.py", line 109, in get_pyaudio
    import pyaudio
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyaudio'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/Anu Nema/Desktop/New folder/alice/alice.py", line 49, in <module>
    takeCommand()
  File "c:/Users/Anu Nema/Desktop/New folder/alice/alice.py", line 30, in takeCommand
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
  File "C:\Users\Anu Nema\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\speech_recognition\__init__.py", line 80, in __init__
    self.pyaudio_module = self.get_pyaudio()
  File "C:\Users\Anu Nema\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\speech_recognition\__init__.py", line 111, in get_pyaudio
    raise AttributeError("Could not find PyAudio; check installation")
AttributeError: Could not find PyAudio; check installation
```

Comment: Have you done ‘pip3 install pyaudio’ in the command line?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). At its current state, your question is not answerable, please edit it with further details and preferably include some code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that this error occurs is because you do not have ‘pyaudio’ installed on your computer. This is a dependency of ‘speech_recognition’ and therefore you must have it if you wish to use ‘speech_recognition’.

You can do this by typing this command into the command line:

```
pip3 install pyaudio
```

This requires you have pip set up on your computer.

This should resolve the error you are having.